# Error while running query on sqlite database react natve

Tags: sql, sqlite, react-native

I'm using the 'react-native-sqlite-storage' plugin from npm.
and my database is located in 'android/app/src/main/res/assets' on android
on Ios, I haven't tried it yet but it seems that it shouldn't be too difficult once I have this one working.

Home.js

```
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');

componentDidMount() {
    var db = SQLite.openDatabase("file.sqlite", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employees a, Departments b WHERE a.department = b.department_id', [], (tx, results) => {
              console.log("Query completed");
            });
        });
    }

    errorCB(err) {
      console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
    }

    successCB() {
      console.log("SQL executed fine");
    }

    openCB() {
      console.log("Database OPENED");
    }
```

the log output I get is :

```
OPEN database: file.sqlite 
new transaction is waiting for open operation
```

Any ideas why this would happen?